# Would “ego sum illi” be a good translation for “I’m him” or “I am him”?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would greatly appreciate any assistance because I am still extremely new to learning Latin but “illi” doesn’t seem right to me which is making me question the entire translation. Thanks.

Comment: No, it's not a good translation. But in order to help you best, can you edit your question to explain why you chose the words you chose and what you are trying to convey? Something you'll learn as you get deeper in Latin is that you can't just do a word-for-word translation.

Comment: I guess what I would be trying to convey is a type of “superiority” in a way. Almost like “I am the one”, how I use it in this context would have a bigger emphasis on “him” so it would be “I am HIM”. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Google Translate fun again: "I am him" (without full stop) translates to "ego sum illi", but "I am him." (with full stop) to "Eum ego." Just to be clear, both are gibberish.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Technically, *ego sum illi* could mean "I am his" with a dative of possession. Not sure I've ever seen that with *sum*, though. Doubtful Google is doing that anyway.

Comment: I would suggest *ipse sum*, ‘I am that same one’.

Answer (score 12):

What you've done, *ego sum illi*, would mean 'I am those people,' because *illi* would in this instance be a nominative plural form. If you want to render 'I am that person'/'I am HIM,' you need the nominative singular *ille*. It seems to me that a form of *ille* works pretty well for meaning and emphasis that you're giving to 'him.'

So:

> *ego sum ille*

Or:

> *ego ille sum*

(Cf. Plautus, *Stichus* 731: *ego tu sum, tu es ego, unianimi sumus*, 'I am you, you are me; we are like-minded.')

Comment: A Petrarchan passage (Contra medicum quendam, Bk. 1) that corroborates your answer: si es ille quem puto (if you are the man I think you are).

Comment: Also corroborating is the foreword to Virgil's Aeneid, *Ille ego, qui quondam gracili modulatus avena
Carmen et egressus silvis vicina coegi
Ut quamvis avido parerent arva colono,
Gratum opus agricolis: at nunc horrentia Martis Arma virumque cano...

Comment: "ego tu sum, tu es ego, unianimi sumus" - This is the Beatles, right? What's the Latin word for walrus?